# Disabling key repeat in Swing

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm developing a Java/Swing application, and I'm making my own handling for key events using a `KeyListener` on my `JFrame`.

My problem is, the key repeat feature of the OS is causing multiple `keyPressed` events to occur when I hold down a key, when I would like to only receive one.

One solution would be to keep the states of the keys in an array, and only accept the event if the state changes.

```java
private boolean keysDown[] = new boolean[0x10000];
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (0 <= key && key <= 0xFFFF) {
        if (keysDown[key]) return;
        keysDown[key] = true;
    }
    // ...
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (0 <= key && key <= 0xFFFF) {
        if (!keysDown[key]) return;
        keysDown[key] = false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This works, but is very clumsy, and while I only seem to find keycodes in the range 0 to 2<sup>16</sup>-1, I'm not sure if ones outside that range can exist. (`getKeyCode()` returns `int`.) Another problem is that pressing down a key, releasing it while in another window, and pressing it again in my application would not register the event.

So, is there a better way to either

- disable key repeat in my application or
- detect repeated events reliably?

Comment: Replace your boolean array with `HashSet<Integer>` or `TreeSet<Integer>`.  The key repeat is a function of the OS, so there is no way to disable it, only account for it.

Comment: @VGR I ended up doing it that way, with a `WindowFocusListener` to clear pressed keys on losing focus. Post that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your boolean array with `HashSet<Integer>` or `TreeSet<Integer>`. The key repeat is a function of the OS, so there is no way to disable it, only account for it.

Comment: Actually on linux you can disable it (if under X11) using `xset -r`. Not sure this is super useful for a real-world app though (I wouldn't like it to be forced to disable my keyboard auto-repeat merely to use some software).